# Future model agnostic db migration rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

The general problem is that a migration could fail if the model is changed in the future by adding a code which doesn't has underpinned by the db.

The scenario is similar to this:
I have a migration like this:

```
def change
  Product.find_each do |product|
    product.prices.each do |price|
      price.supplier_part_number = product.supplier_part_number
      price.save
    end
  end
end
```

The migration is deployed to staging.
Then a state machine is added to the Price model which requires the state attribute.
The add_state migration is deployed to the staging so the Price has the state attribute on dev and on staging.

The decision comes to deploy the app to Production.

And the above shown migration won't be executed because the state attribute isn't there. That is added later...

So it seems that the migration is affected by the future state of the model...

Are there any gems or practices to avoiding these kind of bottlenecks?

Comment: It is bad practice to migrate data like that. Migrations should only contain changes to the data structure.

Comment: Then where should I put the migration like this?

Comment: You should write a rake task

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that is widely accepted in the rails community:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-models-in-your-migrations

So the migration should be changed to this:

```
class MigrateFieldsFromProductToPrice < ActiveRecord::Migration
  class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  end

  def change
    Price.reset_column_information
    Product.find_each do |product|
      product.prices.each do |price|
        price.supplier_part_number = product.supplier_part_number
        price.save
      end
    end
  end
end
```